# set and clearInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I got two functions, increaseSpeed and decreaseSpeed.
They both use clearInterval() then setInterval however something isn't right.

decreaseSpeed slows my speed from 1000 to 5000 however if I use that function 10-20 plus times the speed seems more like 100-500ms.
Also if I use increaseSpeed to increase speed to 50ms and use decreaseSpeed after, decreaseSpeed won't have any effect at all.

This is the set, clear function

```
var updateRate = 1000;
var id = setInterval(myFunction, updateRate);
function myFunction() {     
valClickedFun(1);
   }
```

and decreaseSpeed

```
    function decreaseSpeed(){

        clearInterval(id);
        updateRate = 5000;
        setInterval(myFunction, updateRate);

        console.log(updateRate)
};
```

I got a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avqdcqng/14/) set up, if you click on "Decrease speed" button several times, you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: you wouldn't be able to notice a increase/decrease of 50 ms would you?

Comment: No, that's why I got "IncreaseSpeed" set to 50ms, (it doesn't really increase, just sets it to 50ms) and "decreaseSpeed sets it to 5000ms. 
By setting it to 5000ms over and over again, you can see that the time is more like 500ms or less, as if the function duplicates it self... I don't know how to explain :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign setInterval to id in your functions (decreaseSpeed and increaseSpeed).

```
id = setInterval(myFunction, updateRate);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avqdcqng/15/)

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your fiddle an I think I have found the problem.

When you use the `increaseSpeed` and `decreaseSpeed` functions you need to set the id of the interval to the new interval. This will make sure that the next time you click the Increase or Decrease speed button the previous interval will be cleared.

Example: `id = setInterval(myFunction, updateRate);`

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `setInterval` returns a unique value. You store this in `id` when you initially call `setInterval` but you do not reset it in either `decreaseSpeed` or `increaseSpeed` as you create new intervals.

Because of this, each `clearInterval(id)` call tries to clear the **original** interval, even if it has already been cleared. Any subsequently created intervals are left running. Instead of replacing the existing interval with a faster or slower one, `increaseSpeed` and `decreaseSpeed` add a new interval that runs alongside the existing ones.

Changing

```
setInterval(myFunction, updateRate);
```

to

```
id = setInterval(myFunction, updateRate);
```

should fix it.